# Preference and mail server invalid record data in g cloud MX records for g suite

Tags: gcloud

I am trying to add MX records for g suite but it shows following error "Invalid record data" Error screenshot as follows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDVcQ.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add record as

```
1 aspmx.l.google.com
```

must add a record starting with numerical one to indicate the priority.

more details can be found in the official site https://support.google.com/a/answer/9222085?hl=en